# How to reference a long title with a shorter one

Tags: abbreviations, titles

I am writing a paper, and lets say I have a long name, The Swiss Cheese Competition Act of 1950. How would I refer to it in shorthand so I don't have to write it out in the rest of the paper?

- The Swiss Cheese Competition Act of 1950, henceforth referred to as the Competition Act. The Competition Act ...
- The Swiss Cheese Competition Act of 1950 ("Competition Act"). The Competition Act ...

Comment: I think you'll have to refer to style guides for this.

Comment: I think you mean _henceforth_, not _hereby_.

Comment: You shouldn't have to link the short name to the long name like this unless it's a legal document. Just use the long title once and then the short title (maybe just "the Act") later. But as @NVZ says, you may have a style guide which dictates what you should do.

Comment: Also check out https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/

Comment: @Spencer even if you're not writing a legal document you may have to refer to multiple *act*s. The same could be true of other normative documents such as standards when writing a design spec.

Answer (score 3):

Taking your example, I'd use a more memorable abbreviation, and I'd make the first mention part of a full sentence:

> The Swiss Cheese Competition Act of 1950 (*Swiss Cheese Act*) was enacted in 1950. The stated purpose of the Swiss Cheese Act was to regulate hole sizes to avoid unfair competition.

There are plenty of options -- as always in technical writing, you should prioritise clarity.  Clarity is rarely served by text that reads as legalese (except presumably to lawyers) so *henceforth referred to* or even worse *hereinafter referred to* is of no help.

Comment: Hereinafter I shall endeavor to pen parsimonious, pithy prose, which clearly communicates my cognitions with clarity. ... On a serious note, +1 for a very helpful answer.  :0)

Comment: @Chris H: You might say: "The Swiss Cheese Competition Act of 1950 (Swiss Cheese Act) was enacted in 1950. The stated purpose of the Swiss Cheese Act was to regulate hole sizes to avoid unfair competition." (I've deleted "was an act that" from your sentence.) You wouldn't say "[this act] was an act that was enacted..." - there'd be far too much acting going on there!

Comment: @Kiloran_speaking, yes, I can't remember why I put that in